# What is the query for getting database name in Progress-OpenEdge?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

How can we get database name in **progress openedge** like in **SQL** we can get **database name** by using **show databases;** or **SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;** using **SQL** query to **openedge DB**.

Comment: THis is a cross-post with https://community.progress.com/s/question/0D54Q00008cPhKl/what-the-query-for-getting-database-name?s1oid=00D3000000007FS&OpenCommentForEdit=1&s1nid=0DB4Q000000Gn0b&emkind=chatterPostNotification&s1uid=0054Q00000FNkcK&emtm=1620798754740&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0&t=1620799994993

Answer (score 1):

In ABL you can

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

DO i = 1 TO NUM-DBS:
    MESSAGE LDBNAME (i) SKIP 
            PDBNAME (i) SKIP 
            DBPARAM (i)
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
END.
```

In OpenEdge SQL the SHOW CATALOGS command returns the database/catalog names:

https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference/page/SHOW-CATALOGS.html?_ga=2.234385114.558448476.1620632697-128156788.1596090319

```
SHOW CATALOGS PRO_NAME;
```

Comment: I want in **SQL query** not in **ABL**.

Comment: You tagged your question with "progress-4gl". That gives people the idea that maybe you're using the 4gl engine. Which also contains some (very limited) SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
select db_name() from sysprogress.syscalctable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the link to "Progress Communities" goes away:

> Valeriy Bashkatov (Progress Technologies LLC)
>
> You should run this with a DBA privileged user.
>
> select * from sysprogress.SYSTABLES;
>
> select * from sysprogress.SYSTABLES_FULL;
>
> select * from sysprogress.SYSCOLUMNS where TBL = 'table_name';
>
> select * from sysprogress.SYSCOLUMNS_FULL where TBL = 'table_name';