# how to get all schema list in progress-openedge SQL query

Tags: openedge, progress-db

How to get schema list in Progress OpenEdge SQL query for **PUB** and **SYSPROGRESS**:

[image: Schema]

In this case

[image: Schema Names]

Or for below structure.

```
Sports2000
  ↳ PUB
     ↳ Tables
  ↳ SYSPROGRESS
     ↳ Tables
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the query for getting database name in Progress-OpenEdge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498100/what-is-the-query-for-getting-database-name-in-progress-openedge)

Answer (score 0):

The `schema` you are referring to is the `owner`.

```
select owner, count(*) as '#' from sysprogress.systables group by owner
```

Which will return something like:

```
OWNER       #
PUB         157
SPORTS2020    1
SYSPROGRESS  49
```